# Kotlin. How to get specific subclass of sealed class?

Tags: kotlin, enums, data-class, sealed-class, kotlin-sealed

I'm using kotlin sealed class. And I need to retrieve specific subclass. My sealed class:

```
sealed class Course(
    val type: Type
) {
    data class ProgrammingCourse(val name: String, val detail: String) : Course(Type.PROGRAMMING)
    object LanguageCourse: Course(Type.LANGUAGE)
    .....
}
```

For example I have function which can return `Course`:

```
fun getCourse(): Course { 
    if(...)
      return Course.ProgrammingCourse("test", "test")
    else 
     return Course.LanguageCourse
}
```

In addition, I have a method that can only work with a specific subclass of the `Course` class. Fox example:

```
fun workWithCourse(course: Course.ProgrammingCourse) {
   // here some logic
}
```

And now I'm trying to get the course using the method `getCourse()`, and then pass it to the method `workWithCourse()`

```
fun main() {
  val course = getCourse()
  workWithCourse(course)

}
```

**Error:**

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Course.ProgrammingCourse
Found:
Course
```

But I know the course type - `Type`, parameter that each course has. Can I, knowing this `Type`, cast the course (which I retrieve from `getCourse()` method) to a specific subclass ? Is there such a way ?
Please help me

**P.S.**

I don't need type checks like:

```
if(course is Course.ProgrammingCourse) {
     workWithCourse(course)
}
```

I need the subclass to be automatically inferred by the `Type` parameter, if possible.

**P.S.2**
The need for such a solution is that I have a class that takes a `Course`, it doesn't know anything about a particular course, at the same time the class takes the `Type` that I want to use for identification. This class also receives an interface (by DI) for working with courses, a specific implementation of the interface is provided by the dagger(multibinding) by key, where I have the `Type` as the key. In the same way I want to pass by the same parameter `Type` specific subclass of my `Course` to my interface which working with specific courses.

Comment: *I need the subclass to be automatically inferred by the Type parameter, if possible.* - inferred where? You don't check the `type` property either. What do you want to happen if `getCourse()` returned a `Course.LanugageCourse`?

Comment: What should happen if getCourse() returns LanguageCourse and you pass it to workWithCourse (which sounds like it should only work with ProgrammingCourse) ?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way for automatic inference to the best of my knowledge.

You returned a `Course`, and that's what you have. Being `sealed` here does not matter at all. Generally what you do here is use the `when` expression if you want to statically do different things depending on the type, but if it's just one type (`ProgrammingCourse`) that can be passed to `workWithCourse`, then an `if` is probably right, with dispatch using `as`.

That said, this looks like counter-productive design. If you can only work with one course, why do they even share a top level interface? The way the code is written implies working is a function that can take any course, or should be a method member. Anything else is very confusing. Perhaps `workWithCourse` should take a `Course` and use the `when` expression to dispatch it appropriately?

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin you can specify the class explicitly with `as`.

```kotlin
val course = getCourse()
if (type == Type.PROGRAMMING) {
    workWithCourse(course as Course.ProgrammingCourse)
}
```

*thanks [Joffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1540818/joffrey) for his comment

Comment: `is` is incorrect here, I think you meant `==`

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be asking for is a compile-time guarantee for something that will only be known at runtime. You didn't share the condition used in `getCourse()`, but in general it could return both types.

Therefore, you need to decide what will happen in both cases - that's not something the compiler can decide for you via any "inference".

- If you want the program to throw an exception when `getCourse()` returns something else than a `Course.ProgrammingCourse`, you can *cast* the returned value using `as`:

```kotlin
val course = getCourse() as Course.ProgrammingCourse
workWithCourse(course)
```

- If you don't want to crash, but you only want to call `workWithCourse` in some cases, then you need an `if` or `when` statement to express that choice. For instance, to call it only when the value is of type `Course.ProgrammingCourse`, then you would write the code you already know:

```kotlin
if (course is Course.ProgrammingCourse) {
    workWithCourse(course)
}
```

Or with a `when` statement:

```kotlin
val course = getCourse()
when (course) {
    is Course.ProgrammingCourse -> workWithCourse(course)
    is Course.LanguageCourse -> TODO("do something with the other value")
}
```

The `when` is better IMO because it forces you (or other devs in the team) to take a look at this `when` whenever you (or they) add a new subclass of the sealed class. It's easy to forget with an `if`.

You can also decide to not test the actual type, and focus on the `type` property like in @grigory-panov's answer, but that is brittle because it relies on an implicit relationship between the `type` property and the actual type of the value:

```kotlin
val course = getCourse()
if (type == Type.PROGRAMMING) {
    workWithCourse(course as Course.ProgrammingCourse)
}
```

The main point of using sealed classes is so you can use their actual type instead of a manually managed `type` property + casts. So I'd say use *only* `is X` and don't set a `type` property at all. Using a sealed class allows Kotlin to type-check a bunch of things, it's more powerful than using such a property.